# Passing a jscolor selection variable from jquery to php not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using the jscolor.js function to display a colour picker. User selects a colour which is then fed into mysql for later usage. Problem is I can echo/alert the selected colour but it is not being passed to php. If I hard code it it works fine. Anyone have a suggestion on what I am missing.

```
<?php

include ('config.php');

$get_coords = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM color WHERE color_id = '1'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_coords)) {
$color_id = $row['color_id'];
$color = $row['color'];

echo "<div style=color:#$color;>Select a color:</div> <input id='myField1'>";
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

var myPicker = new jscolor.color(document.getElementById('myField1'), {});
myPicker.fromString('<?php echo $color; ?>');

$("#myField1").change(function() {
alert(myPicker);
$.post('updatecolor.php', { 'color': myPicker });
});
});

</script>
```

updatecolor.php

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usr, $db_pass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error());

mysqli_select_db($link, $db_name) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error());

$color=$_POST['color'];

$sql = "UPDATE color SET color = '$color' WHERE color_id = '1'";

mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die("Error updating Coords :".mysqli_error());

echo "success";

?>
```

Comment: should't you get the color selected inside the `change` block?

Comment: Do a network trace using developer tools, is the post going through?

Comment: Ran the trace, if I comment out the $.post line no error if I leave it in it errors with TypeError: Can only call NodeList.item on instances of NodeList. As I stated earlier if hard code 1234 for example in $.post('updatecolor.php', { 'color': '1234' }); it works fine if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorted now.

I've changed the PHP to:

```
echo "<div id='mypick' style=color:#$color;><h1>Select a color:</h1></div>";
```

And changed the JQuery to:

```
var myPicker = $("#myField1").val();
$.post('updatecolor.php', { color:myPicker });
document.getElementById('mypick').style.color = myPicker;
```